# Pi-hole on Docker on QNAP

Tags: docker, qnap, pihole

I have installed a fresh Pi-hole container on the Container Station on a QNAP NAS running latest QTS. All goes well but when the container starts it appears that the Pi-hole versions are quite old (5.2.4 from January 2021). Pi-hole core is currently on version 5.10 from April 2020.

To install the container I carried out the following steps:

- Container Station "Create" Searched for "pihole" and selected "Docker
  Hub" tab
- Clicked on "install" for pihole/pihole
- Selected "latest" from dropdown
- Chose appropriate options

It does not make sense to carry out an in-place upgrade on the container. I cannot work out if the method I have used is wrong to get the latest version, or if the container repository I have accessed has an old version. Can anyone put me straight?

```
Versions NAS: TS-251D QTS: 5.0.0.1986 Container Station: 2.6.0.243
```

Comment: Why can't you install whatever version wants to be installed from the repository, at that point you are now dealing with a base install, which should allow you to upgrade using the documented process that applies to every version.

Comment: I think it is very confusing on the QNAP platform just which version of an image one is using. I suspect this is at the heart of my problem.